# Chrome: SVG background-image on Retina display

Tags: css, svg, retina-display

The issue: SVG loaded via `<img>` or `<embed>` are rendered correctly (i.e. high pixel-per-unit) on Retina devices, however, when the same SVG file is loaded via CSS `background-image` property it is rendered poorly (seems like device resolution is not accounted).

Is there any chance I can talk my browser into correct SVG rendering on devices with higher pixel density? Reducing image size via `background-size` didn't work; hacks like `transform: translateZ(0)` didn't work either.

**Update:** this issue seems to be specific to Chrome 39 and earlier.

Comment: Of course, it seems to be specific to Chrome 39. Sorry I didn't specify it earlier.

Comment: Please file a bugreport at http://crbug.com with a complete testcase. Have you tested if it works correctly in later versions?

Comment: It appears to work correctly in Chrome Canary.

Answer (score 2):

I did some testing and it appears to only look crappy when I apply a border.

With border: 1px solid #555:

[image: Border]

Without border:

[image: No norder]

Here is my testing code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">

    div {
      background-image: url('search.svg');
      width: 38px;
      height: 38px;
      border: 1px solid #555;
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:** Also, if the element dimensions is larger than the width and height specified in the svg file, the image will get pixelated. Using background-size: contain; seems to solve that as long as the aspect ratio is the same.

**Edit 2:** Turns out background-repeat also affects the rendering. Setting it to 'no-repeat' generally makes it look right.